# MYSQL Error at line 1 - but phpmyadmin says no errors

Tags: php, mysql

heres my SQL query

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE` SET `cdOwnerId` = '0', `cdArtist` = 'Amarillo', `cdTitle` = 'Tony Christie', `cdOrder` = '1', `cdType` = 'album', `cdNotes` = 'MAKE THIS WORK LATER', `cdId` = '0006', `cdObtainable` = '8'; 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` SET `cdOwnerId` = '0', `cdArtist` = 'My Way', `cdTitle` = 'Frank Sinatra', `cdOrder` = '2', `cdType` = 'album', `cdNotes` = 'MAKE THIS WORK LATER', `cdId` = '0001', `cdObtainable` = '8'; 

INSERT INTO `TABLE` SET `cdOwnerId` = '0', `cdArtist` = 'Piano concerto 21', `cdTitle` = 'Mozart', `cdOrder` = '3', `cdType` = 'album', `cdNotes` = 'MAKE THIS WORK LATER', `cdId` = '0003', `cdObtainable` = '8';
```

and the result i get is...

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO TABLE SET `cdId` = '0', `cdArtist` = 'My Way', `m' at line 1

but via phpMyAdmin, it takes it, but via PHP, nope...

**Update**

Still nothing with..

```
 INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`cdOwnerId`, `cdArtist`,`cdTitle`, `cdOrder`, `cdType`, `cdNotes`, `cdId`, `cdObtainable`) VALUES ('2', 'Time to say goodbye', 'Katherine Jenkins', '1', 'album', 'MAKE THIS WORK LATER', '0005', '8'),('2', 'Piano concerto 21 andante', 'Mozart', '2', 'album', 'MAKE THIS WORK LATER', '0003', '8'),('2', 'Wind Beneath My Wings', 'Bette Midler', '3', 'album', 'MAKE THIS WORK LATER', '0002', '8');
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('2', 'Time to say goodbye', 'Katherine Jenkins', '1', 'album', 'MAKE THIS WORK ' at line 1

Table structure...

```
`musicCdsId` int(8) NOT NULL,
`cdOwnerId` int(20) NOT NULL,
`cdArtist` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`cdTitle` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`cdOrder` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`cdType` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`cdNotes` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`cdId` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`cdObtainable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`cdCost` int(5) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Loop for multiple cds

```
if(isset($_POST['musicDetails']) && is_array($_POST['musicDetails'])){
        $orderCount = 1;
        foreach($_POST['musicDetails'] as $detail){
            if(!empty($detail['title']) || !empty($detail['artist'])){
                if(!empty($cdDetails)){$cdDetails .= ",";}
                $cdDetails .= "(".dbsafe(mysql_insert_id()).", ".dbsafe($detail['artist']).", ".dbsafe($detail['title']).", ".dbsafe($orderCount).", ".dbsafe($detail['order']).", ".dbsafe("MAKE THIS WORK LATER").", ".dbsafe($detail['mycdid']).", ".dbsafe(8).")";
                $orderCount++;
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: You try to execute 3 queries at once in PHP. That does not work. Do them one after the other

Comment: [insert into table PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Comment: What is the field type of `cdOrder`, `cdId` and `cdObtainable`? I assume `integer` and you're attempting to insert them as `string`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue if you use 'INSERT INTO table-name SET'. 
Though more frequently used are 'UPDATE SET'  and 'INSERT INTO table-name (column-names ...) VALUES (...)'. Here, the SET clause indicates the column names explicitly.

The issue here might be different (as I am not sure about the datatype of cdOwnerId/cdId is int or anything else) . In some cases 'integer' datatype do not accept character way of value insertion (`cdOwnerId` = '0' , `cdId` = '0006').

You may  try replacing those as (`cdOwnerId` = 0 , `cdId` = 6) and check

http://mysqlrockstar.blogspot.in/

Comment: i am afraid no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Try with this:

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE` 
(`cdOwnerId`, `cdArtist`, `cdTitle`, `cdOrder`, `cdType`, `cdNotes`, `cdId`, `cdObtainable`)
VALUES
('0', 'Amarillo', 'Tony Christie', '1', 'album', 'MAKE THIS WORK LATER', '0006', '8'),
('0', 'My Way', 'Frank Sinatra', '2', 'album', 'MAKE THIS WORK LATER', '0001', '8'),
('0', 'Mozart', 'Piano concerto 21', '2', 'album', 'MAKE THIS WORK LATER', '0003', '8');
```

Comment: Nope....

INSERT INTO `TABLE` 
     (`cdOwnerId`, `cdArtist`, `cdOrder`, `cdType`, `cdNotes`, `cdId`, `cdObtainable`) VALUES ('2', 'Time to say goodbye', 'Katherine Jenkins', '1', 'album', 'MAKE THIS WORK LATER', '0005', '8'),('2', 'Piano concerto 21 andante', 'Mozart', '2', 'album', 'MAKE THIS WORK LATER', '0003', '8'),('2', 'Wind Beneath My Wings', 'Bette Midler', '3', 'album', 'MAKE THIS WORK LATER', '0002', '8');You have an error in your SQL syntax; ... to use near '('2', 'Time to say goodbye', 'Katherine Jenkins', '1', 'album', 'MAKE THIS WORK ' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

try another method :

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE` (`cdOwnerId`, `cdArtist`, `cdTitle`, `cdOrder`, `cdType`, `cdNotes`, `cdId`, `cdObtainable`) VALUES (0, 'Amarillo', 'Tony Christie', 1, 'album', 'MAKE THIS WORK LATER', '0006', 8);
```

By preference, within a PHP script, use ' instead of `

Answer (score 0):

The fix actually was to not use ' in the loop...

.dbsafe($detail[artist]).

Go figure!